# How to get value from a NSDictionnary which is in a NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

i would like to get a value which is a String. 
The value is in a NSDictionnary, but the NSDIctionnary is in a NSArray.

How can i get the value ? for exemple i want to get the string which has for key "path"

Thanks for your help.

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>path</key>
        <string>2.mov</string>
        <key>width</key>
        <string>768</string>
        <key>height</key>
        <string>1024</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
[[array objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"path"]
```

Comment: doesnt work, don't forget that there is a NSDictionnary in the NSArray.

Comment: @user1256827:  if that code doesn't work, you haven't got a dictionary in an array, you have something else, because the code is right as long as the dioctionary is the first object in the array.  Try `NSLog(@"%@", theArray);` and posting the output.